# How to use if/else condition with onclick in selenium webdriver?

Tags: java, selenium, automation

In selenium webdriver i want to use if/else condition with java. Each steps need to be clicked and need to execute once has been selected . With the condition of Number_Select.NumberRandom(driver, 2).click(); = selection 2 of if else statement from numberRandom. For example , so my question is once the testcase run it only click one number , suppose to click 2 random number. Kindly advise

TestCases :

```
@Test(description = "Login Page Test" , enabled = true)
    public void faaaa() throws Exception {
        try{
            driver = new FirefoxDriver();
            SignIn_Action.Execute(driver);
            Menu_Select.Menu_Selection(driver, 2).click();
            MenuLottery_Select.Menu_Selection(driver, 1).click();
            MenuSubTab_Select.MenuSubTab_1(driver, 3).click();
            Number_Select.NumberRandom(driver, 2).click();
            //SignIn_Action.Logout_Session(driver);
            //Log.info("Login Successful");
        }catch (Exception e){

            System.out.println("Test 1"); 
            //Log.error(e.getMessage());
            throw (e);
        }

    }
```

Number_Select :

```
public static WebElement NumberRandom(WebDriver driver, int selection)
            throws Exception {

        if (selection == 1) {
            Thread.sleep(1500);
            element = driver.findElement(By
                    .xpath("//*[@id='lottery']/div[3]/dl/dd/i[8]"));
        } else if (selection == 2) {
            Thread.sleep(1500);
            element = driver.findElement(By
                    .xpath("//*[@id='lottery']/div[3]/dl[1]/dd/i[8]"));
            element = driver.findElement(By
                    .xpath("//*[@id='lottery']/div[3]/dl[2]/dd/i[3]"));
        } else if (selection == 3) {
            Thread.sleep(1500);
            element = driver.findElement(By
                    .xpath("//*[@id='lottery']/div[3]/dl[1]/dd/i[8]"));
            element = driver.findElement(By
                    .xpath("//*[@id='lottery']/div[3]/dl[2]/dd/i[3]"));
            element = driver.findElement(By
                    .xpath("//*[@id='lottery']/div[3]/dl[3]/dd/i[5]"));
        } else if (selection == 4) {
            Thread.sleep(1500);
            element = driver.findElement(By
                    .xpath("//*[@id='lottery']/div[3]/dl[1]/dd/i[8]"));
            element = driver.findElement(By
                    .xpath("//*[@id='lottery']/div[3]/dl[2]/dd/i[3]"));
            element = driver.findElement(By
                    .xpath("//*[@id='lottery']/div[3]/dl[3]/dd/i[5]"));
            element = driver.findElement(By
                    .xpath("//*[@id='lottery']/div[3]/dl[4]/dd/i[1]"));
        } else if (selection == 5) {
            Thread.sleep(1500);
            element = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='lottery']/div[3]/dl[1]/dd/i[8]"));
            element = driver.findElement(By
                    .xpath("//*[@id='lottery']/div[3]/dl[2]/dd/i[3]"));
            element = driver.findElement(By
                    .xpath("//*[@id='lottery']/div[3]/dl[3]/dd/i[5]"));
            element = driver.findElement(By
                    .xpath("//*[@id='lottery']/div[3]/dl[4]/dd/i[1]"));
            element = driver.findElement(By
                    .xpath("//*[@id='lottery']/div[3]/dl[5]/dd/i[9]"));//*[@id="lottery"]/div[3]/dl[1]/dd/i[1]
        } else {
            Log.error("Unable to select product list");
            System.out.println("Unable select product list");
        }

        return element;
    }
```

Comment: Not quite to understand what do you want?. However, I'm so confused with the way you set element in each condition. only last element is valid and could be return.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`NumberRandom` is returning only one WebElement. Even if you are locating several WebElements in the same `if` block each time you override the last value `element` had and the last one is being returned to `faaaa()`. If you want to click all the elements you need to insert the `click()` to the method

```
else if (selection == 2) {
    Thread.sleep(1500);
     element = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='lottery']/div[3]/dl[1]/dd/i[8]")).click();
     element = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='lottery']/div[3]/dl[2]/dd/i[3]")).click();
}
```

As a side note, you should avoid using `Thread.sleep`. If you want to make sure the element is clickable use explicit wait and [expected conditions](https://selenium.googlecode.com/git/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/ExpectedConditions.html)

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//*[@id='lottery']/div[3]/dl[1]/dd/i[8]"))).click();
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//*[@id='lottery']/div[3]/dl[2]/dd/i[3]"))).click();
```

This will wait up to 10 seconds for the element to be clickable before clicking on it.

Comment: Thanks for help and info . Good Work Bro